# How to increase the size of the CheckBox in ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: c#, checkbox, drawing, contextmenu, dpi

I'm using `ContextMenuStripper` and added some `ToolStripMenuItem`. I have enabled `CheckOnClick`. The checkbox rendering is looks fine in 100_DPI, but in 200_DPI, the checkbox is not scaling properly based on DPI factor.

How can we increase the size of the CheckBox? Please share your ideas.

Reference Links: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-display-option-buttons-in-a-menustrip-windows-forms)

Thanks and Regards,

Sindhu

[image: 100dpi]
[image: 200dpi]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which platform you're using, but if you are using winforms, try to change the form's property `AutoScaleMode` from `Font` to `Dpi` to see if it helps.

I also found the tutorial: [How to: Configure MenuStrip Check Margins and Image Margins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-configure-menustrip-check-margins-and-image-margins). You can try to change the margin of the check and see if it works out.

One possible solution is set the `ImageScaling` property from `None` to `SizeToFit` along with the upper `AutoScaleMode`. Could you give it a try if these work?